# Magento UI Component: change placeholder if input is required

Tags: magento2

I would like to have an asterisk after the placeholder in any inputs that are required. I see that there is logic in the default markup that relates to the input being required:

`'aria-required': required,`

How can I determine if an input is required?

I should be able to determine if an input is required and then change the placeholder like so:

`placeholder: required? placeholder + '*' : placeholder,`

However, `required` is a function and so using it in this context doesn't work, it always evaluates to `true`.